# How do I determine the "active" view when using the Xamarin Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

We're using C# Xamarin Android in VS2017. We have a recycler view that is being used to allow users to swipe left and right and view a compound control. I am keen to know whether it is possible to determine which instance of the compound control is currently "active". By that, I mean which one is occupying at least 50% of the screen real estate.

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence. What is mean which one is occupying at least 50% of the screen real estate? Do you want to know which views are being displayed in RecyclerView?

Comment: The views move across the screen from side to side. When the movement is complete, a single view will be displayed that occupies the whole width of the screen. We want to know which record is being displayed. However, ideally we want to know this information before the view occupies 100% of the width. As the user scrolls, there will usually be two views being displayed - one view is going from 100% to 0% (i.e. it is being moved off the screen). The second view is going from 0% to 100% as it replaces the previous view. We want to know about this second view.